# jQuery replaceWith throws back error after adding jQuery mobile library

Tags: jquery

I use this jQuery code to replace my HTML elements.

```
$("input#img").replaceWith($("input#img").val('').clone(true));
```

This code works well but my problem is that when I include jQuery mobile 1.4.5 in to my HTML page I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught DOMExecption: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this error?

Comment: What's the point of the code at all? You're replacing an element with *itself* after emptying the value...? Just empty the value and don't bother calling `replaceWith()` at all - it's completely redundant in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input#img").val('');
```

This will set the `value` to `''` for the `<input>` element with `id` that is `img`.